# Netty: adding a form field with binary data to a HTTP POST request

Tags: java, http, post, arrays, netty

In Netty there is a `HttpPostRequestEncoder` class which has an `addBodyAttribute(String name, String value)` method. I need to POST a value with binary data, but I can not find a method which takes `byte[] value` instead of `String value`. Is it easily achievable by any other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging into Netty sources I've found somewhat looking as a solution:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[200];
...
DefaultFullHttpRequest req = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(httpVersion, HttpMethod.POST, uri);
DefaultHttpDataFactory factory = new DefaultHttpDataFactory();
HttpPostRequestEncoder enc = new HttpPostRequestEncoder(factory, req, false, CharsetUtil.UTF_8, HttpPostRequestEncoder.EncoderMode.RFC1738);
Attribute attr = factory.createAttribute(req, "someBinaryVar");
attr.setContent(io.netty.buffer.Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(buf));
enc.addBodyHttpData(attr);
...
enc.finalizeRequest();
```

Comment: As the standard says: "Control names and values are escaped." so when you do `enc.addBodyHttpData(attr)`, the encoder will escape the name and value using charset if in `x-www-form-urlencoded`. If in `multipart/form-data`, it should work. So multipart argument should be `true` and not `false`, so `new HttpPostRequestEncoder(factory, req, true, CharsetUtil.UTF_8, HttpPostRequestEncoder.EncoderMode.RFC1738)`;.It should work...

Comment: The standard is not too specific about different charsets. It says that all non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by "_a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character._" As far as I understand this, the data is considered as a sequence of ASCII characters no matter what charset it really is in.

Comment: Whatever the charset, as you said, the data is supposed to be a sequence of ASCII, not binary. So the reason you need to use multipart/form-data IMHO.

Comment: What do you mean by "a sequence of ASCII, not binary"? It is a sequence of bytes. A byte cannot be "either binary or ASCII", it's just an 8-bit number (between 0 and 255 inclusively). And ASCII is just a table which contains graphical representation for each number between 0 and 255. So for each byte you can find according graphical representation in ASCII table.

Comment: Well, strictly saying - yes, the original 1963 version was 7-bit, and later on extended 8-bit variants appeared. Nevertheless, the last alphanumeric character 'z' has decimal code 122. All greater codes are just considered non-alphanumeric, so it does not matter if they are less or greater than 127 (the upper 7-bit threshold). They are just escaped as %HH, thus making any byte sequence eligible for url-encoding.

Comment: I also found [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Binary_data)

Comment: Yeah! Right ;-) I missed this one and I learned something tonight!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One may try to use the following (supposely wrong) combination if in standard POST (application/x-www-form-urlencoded):
1) Creating his/her own `data = InterfaceHttpData` (based for instance on `MemoryAttribute`) and filling it with a `ChannelBuffer`/`ByteBuffer` (according to Netty version) build from the given byte[] (`setContent()`)

2) Use `addBodyHttpData(InterfaceHttpData data)`

But the issue is, as far as I know, RFC does not allow "byte" for application/x-www-form-urlencoded ; therefore the value will have to be encoded using default charset, which is likely to not produce the correct answear.

Edit: To leverage this, one can create the encoder accordingly to use multipart:

```
new HttpPostRequestEncoder(factory, req, true);
```

It should work...

A) So possibly you will have to first encoded your "byte" in a "text" way (7 bit way as BASE64 encoding), then create your attribute using the default constructor `addBodyAttribute(String name, String value)` and then decoding on server side the value back to binary using BASE64 decoder.

=> But this needs the server to perform special decoding action (BASE64)

B) Another option would be to create a multipart POST request and then create a "fictive" file upload, using for instance `MemoryFileUpload`, using the `setContent()` from your own `ChannelBuffer`/`ByteBuffer` (according to Netty version) build from the given byte[] ; therefore the server side will have to handle the bynary content as usual (no decoding needed).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. About `x-www-form-urlencoded`: [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) does not say it is not compatible with binary data. Although it recommends using `multipart/form-data` encoding to transfer binary data for efficiency. But there is no method in Netty taking byte[] as an argument. File upload (and quoted-printable or base64 encoding) is not an option as it requires modification of server-side scripts, which will cause compatibility issues.

Comment: The standard says: "Control names and values are escaped." so binary values cannot be used as is.